# A generalized cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

I found on Wikipedia a generalization of 3D cross product which is a multilinear map that in N-D links an N-1-tuple of vectors to a vector which is orthogonal to all the previous one.
I found that in this site there are some discussion about it
[Cross product in > 3d](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674052/cross-product-in-3d)

Unfortunately both the article and the discussion above do not contain a citation for these results.
Can you please tell me where I can find an open source publication that treats this topic? 
It could seem impossible but I haven't managed to find it anywhere yet.

Comment: What is more "open source" than Wikipedia?

Comment: What do you mean by an "open source publication"? Software can be open source, but publications are usually not. Do you mean "peer-reviewed" instead? // Also, why do you require a citation? Is a proof not enough to convince you?

Comment: Perhaps the commenters could recommend a book that explains the material and its applications?

Comment: Isn’t it essentially a way to compute a null vector of an $(n-1)\times n$ matrix that meets certain length and orientation criteria?

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to take the exterior product of your $n-1$ vectors and then take the Hodge star.

Comment: In Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds Chapter 4, towards the end of the section on Algebraic preliminaries, he introduces the concept of cross products of $n-1$ vectors $v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}$ which are elements of $\Bbb{R}^n$. The construction is pretty much the same as Steven's answer in the link you posted. As usual, Spivak makes you work out the properties of cross products in the form of guided problem sets.

Comment: Thanks to peek-a-boo for suggesting me Spivak's book on the topic, that was exactly what I was looking for